# Why is my html select not selecting the first value of the data?

Tags: html, angular

I have two nearly identical select options, one is showing the first value of the options in the select box as I expect but the other isn't.

This one does not select the first value as I expect:

```
<div class="col-3 col-md-1 text-center">
    <select name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="item.quantity">
        <option *ngFor="let quantity of quantities" [value]="quantity.value">
            {{quantity.value}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Data for the above select box: (I expect the value of 1 to automatically show in the select box but it doesn't).

```
this.quantities = [
  {value: 1 },
  {value: 2 },
  {value: 3 },
  {value: 4 },
  {value: 5 },
  {value: 6 },
  {value: 7 },
  {value: 8 },
  {value: 9 },
  {value: 10 }
];
```

This one shows the first value of the select box as expected:

```
<select name="exp_year" [(ngModel)]="order.customer.payment.exp_year">
  <option *ngFor="let expYear of expYears">
      {{expYear.year}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Data for this select: (2019 is shown in the select box as expected):

```
this.expYears = [
  { year: '2019' },
  { year: '2020' },
  { year: '2021' },
  { year: '2022' },
  { year: '2023' },
  { year: '2024' },
  { year: '2025' },
  { year: '2026' },
  { year: '2027' },
  { year: '2028' },
];
```

Comment: could it be that u might reversed something. As my stackblitz said, that quantities were showing and expYears didnt. Then I simply added the ```[value]="expYear.value"``` to the options as well. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-baz62p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: sorry I meant ```[value]="expYear.year"```. It seems to me that this might not have a valid value ---> ```order.customer.payment.exp_year```

Comment: With the quantities select, I tried it with both [value="quantity.value" and without this, the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to init the select box to set a default value. [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iwrlbg)

**.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  quantity = 2;
  quantityList = [
    { value: 1 },
    { value: 2 },
    { value: 3 },
    { value: 4 },
    { value: 5 },
    { value: 6 },
    { value: 7 },
    { value: 8 },
    { value: 9 },
    { value: 10 }
  ];
}
```

**.html**

```
<select name="quantity" [(ngModel)]="quantity">
  <option *ngFor="let quantity of quantityList" [value]="quantity.value">
    {{quantity.value}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: This would work ordinarily but not for my use case. I am displaying multiple rows on the page with each having a select element so I cannot have a single quantity field in the component. Each row needs to have it's own [(ngModel)]="quantity.value"

Comment: yep, even then you need to init the value. `quantity` can be an array, do you want me to edit the post with multiple select boxes?

Comment: It would be instructive.